# Test data couldn't able to read from properties file

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-objects, properties-file

I got an error in my selenium program. I am using page object design pattern. And I want reading test data from properties file.
But it couldn't able to read ? Any one please help me to solve
page object

```
package pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class HomePage {
    @FindBy(how= How.NAME, using = "username")
    WebElement username;
    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using = "password")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id=\'login-container\']/form/div[3]/div/p/input[1]" )
    WebElement button;

    //enter  username
    public void  userLogin(String user, String pass)
    {
        username.sendKeys(user);
        password.sendKeys(pass);
        button.click();
    }

}
```

steps

```
package steps;


import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import pageobjects.ClientPage;
import pageobjects.HomePage;

import util.DriverManager;


public class LoginSteps {

    public HomePage Login(String nam, String pas) {
        HomePage homePageObj = PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.driver, HomePage.class);
        homePageObj.userLogin(nam,pas);

        return homePageObj;
    }


}
```

Util

```
 package util;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
 * Created by naveen on 29/11/16.
 */
public class DriverManager {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;

    public DriverManager() throws IOException {
        // Get baseUrl property
        File file = new File("home/naveen/IdeaProjects/QberTestCase"+"config.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //load properties file
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        // Start driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/naveen/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

test

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pageobjects.HomePage;
import steps.LoginSteps;
import util.DriverManager;

public class ReadFileData extends DriverManager
{


    @Test
    public void initDriver() {
        //Arrange
        HomePage page = new LoginSteps().Login(prop.getProperty("nam"), prop.getProperty("pass"));

    }


    }
```

properties file

```
config.properties
    baseUrl="http://qmsadm"
    nam="naveen"
    pass="789555"
```

Comment: Add error which you got after execution of above script.

Comment: @BharatMane  currently there is no error couldn't read the config.properties file

Comment: you may confirm once your property file path. Modify it from starting folder of you driver.
 like- "D:/home/naveen/IdeaProjects/QberTestCase/config.properties"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added wrong code in your **"Steps"** Class.
Check below sample code -How data is loaded from properties file-

```
    public void loadPropertiesFile()
    {
        File file = new File(filepath + "object_Repo.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //load properties file
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver=getDriver();
    }

    public void loginSteps() throws IOException
    {
        homePage obj1= new homePage(driver);
        obj1.userLogin(prop.getProperty("nam"), prop.getProperty("pas"));
        return homePageObj;
    }

}
```

In your code you missed to write code for loading test data from properties file-

**prop.getProperty("nam"), prop.getProperty("pas")**

Let me know if it works...

Comment: Absolutely right..At the time of loading properties file, we are always using-  prop.getProperty(" ") for particular single data, if we want to pass multiple test data add it in a similar way separated with the comma.

Comment: @Bharat Mane I have got an error in my code . Can you please check? I edited my code. You can see in the above code

Comment: where is your Obj1?  You created an object of homepage as 'page' so use it instead of obj1. Also check parameters you used in your properties file- pas instead of pass

Comment: will modify your test class plz check updated code..

Comment: I was modified your test class plz check updated code in Test class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52913/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-bharat-mane).

Comment: @BharatMane   yes I got the result .Thank you.

Comment: @BharatMane   please help me .I f want to pass multiple set of data like valid, invalid.  nam=nav, pas=12, nam=vbfdd, pas=23, nam=rrtr,pas=233,nam=ewqe,pas=3213. How I change my code please help me

Comment: For testing same Login functionality with multiple test data you can use Excel sheet instead of properties file.

Comment: I will ping you whenever I will be free for discussion chat. right now I'm is in office.

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"**Cannot navigate
>   to invalid URL**"}

In your `DriverManager` you have an empty `baseurl`.

```
String baseUrl="";
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

From the Java documentation:

> void get(java.lang.String url)
>
> - Parameters: url - The URL to load. It
>     is best to **use a fully qualified URL**

An empty string is not a url, not even close :)

In the `ReadFileData` class you initiate the Driver, but without an url.

Quick fix is to add a real url that can be loaded to the DriverManager.

Maybe you should move the properties loading to the DriverManager? To populate the baseurl. Also maybe ask some developers to help you debug Java errors, you really need to learn and read them.

Example:

```
public DriverManager() {
    // Get baseUrl property
    File file = new File("config.properties");
    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(fileInput);
    fileInput.close()       
    baseUrl = prop.getProperty('baseUrl');

    // Start driver        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/naveen/chromedriver");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. I got a new error  . I want to read the test data from properties file.\

Comment: Now your baseurl is null, leading to this error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

Comment: you have to give baseUrl a valid url in your get, so you need to set baseUrl before you do the get somehow.

Comment: I set the baseUrl value in the properties file.

Comment: when I put the baseurl value in the DriverManager class file It will load. my intention is to read from properties file.

Comment: So you first have to read the properties file, then use the properties to change the baseurl and then do the driver.get. Not the other way around. Seems logical not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52853/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-niels-van-reijmersdal).

Comment: No, i am working. :) Ask your local senior developers to help you with this. I also think you should do this more often, work with other developers and learn from them.

Comment: When you are free please answer to my post. There is no senior java developers in my company

Comment: Any developer would do I think, not just senior. I also do not think Java knowledge is required. I added an example to my answer which switches the loading of properties and opening the driver around for you. This should give you an idea. Not sure syntax is 100% correct, but has been 5 years since I wrote any Java. Goodluck

Comment: Our developers couldn't find a solution any member of this Software Quality Assurance & Testing  will help ?

Comment: This is a programming question and not a SQA&testing question. Please consult http://stackoverflow.com. On a sidenote I think your developers should shame them selves, this issues is solvable with basic debugging and problem solving skills, any medior developer should be able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and share your feedback

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExecuteTest {
    static Keywords keyword;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Keywords key = new Keywords();
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\eclipse-workspace\\PROJECT2\\src\\objectrepositoryproperty\\ObjectRepository.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("OR");
        Iterator row = sheet.iterator();
        while (row.hasNext()) {
            Row rowIterator = (Row) row.next();
            Iterator cellItr = rowIterator.cellIterator();
            while (cellItr.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) cellItr.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    a.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    a.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    a.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    a.add(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

              for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){

            if (a.get(i).equals("openbrowser")) {

                String keyword =(String)a.get(i);
                String data =(String)a.get(i+1);
                String objectname =(String)a.get(i+2);
                String runmode =(String)a.get(i+3);
                System.out.println(keyword);
                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println(objectname);
                System.out.println(runmode);
                if(runmode.equals("yes")) {
                    key.openbrowser();

                    }
            }
            if (a.get(i).equals("navigate")) {
                String keyword =(String)a.get(i);
                String data =(String)a.get(i+1);
                String objectname =(String)a.get(i+2);
                String runmode =(String)a.get(i+3);
                System.out.println(keyword);
                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println(objectname);
                System.out.println(runmode);
                if(runmode.equals("yes")) {
                    key.navigate(data);
                }

            }



            }


    }
}
```

keyword.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Keywords {
           static FirefoxDriver driver;


    public void openbrowser() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver");

           driver = new FirefoxDriver();

           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.HOURS);


    }
    public void navigate (String data) {
           driver.get("www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Have a look here at [how to answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).